# How to model this MILP problem in python?

Tags: python, mixed-integer-programming, branch-and-bound

I have a problem that I want to solve but I cant figure out how to model it Before asking here I made research and find things that will help but I couldnt wrap my head around it. Example of problem I have below

So I have many items lets say 40, each item has 2 or 3 features and each feature is useful only if there are 3,4,5,... of them depending on feature.

**Objective** is getting max amount of *different useful features* with 10 *different items*

**Example** (feature a is useful if 3 or more different items include a, feature b is useful if 5 or more different items include b, c 8 or more items etc)

```
Items   Features (a,b,c,...)
item1   a,c,d
item2   a,b
item3   a,b,e,
item4   a,c
item5   b,e,f
item6   b,d,e
item7   b,c,d
item8   c,f
item9   c,d,e
item10  d,f
...     ...
```

one example combination

```
item1+item2+...+item10 = a(3), b(5)
```

so a and b useful features (c is not useful because there are 5 we need 8 to make it useful)

I think I want to model a mixed integer linear program and solve it with a branch and bound solver The objective is the number of features weight for each item and each feature(?) I thought about modelling this as knapsack problem but then I couldnt figure out how to apply this like capacity is 10 but value and weight? there is min requirement for features to be useful,  I need some guidance or general algorithm to confront this problem, I can investigate further if I have something to start with

Comment: In the example you have 3 items with 'a' feature, but in the output you write a(3). It's correct?

Answer (score 2):

My approach would be:

## Step 1: Develop mathematical model

Get a piece of paper and write down a mathematical model. E.g.:

Data:

```
 a(i,f) = 1   if item i has feature f
          0   otherwise
 K(f)   = number of items with feature f needed to be useful
 N      = number of items to select
```

Binary Variables:

```
 x(i) = 1    if item i is selected
        0    otherwise

 u(f) = 1    if feature f is useful in selection
        0    otherwise
```

Model:

```
  maximize sum(f,u(f))
  subject to 
       sum(i,x(i)) = N
       u(f)*K(f) <= sum(i, a(i,f)*x(i))   for all f
```

## Step 2: implementation

This should now be trivial. Which is the purpose of first writing down the mathematical model.